# How to interpret the Precision Recall AUC

Tags: metric, auc

The ROC AUC has an intuitive interpretation: the probability that the score of a randomly sampled 1-labeled item will be higher than a randomly sampled 0-labeled item.

Is there a similar interpretation to the Precision Recall AUC?

Answer (score 1):

No, to my knowledge there is no similar property for the Precision Recall AUC. In fact I think it's not very common to use the PR AUC for evaluation. As far as I know, a PR curve is used mostly to visualize the relation between precision and recall. But there could be usages that I'm not aware of.